# smtp send mail not sending anything

Tags: asp.net, smtpclient

I am trying to update the credentials that are being used for sending emails.

I am updating to use office 365. Here is what i have set in my config file. No email is being sent.

```
<smtp from="registrar@mysite.com">
            <network password="mypassword" userName="user@mysite.com" host="mail.mysite.com" 
            targetName="STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
```

Comment: Any error did you get?

Comment: got it working. I have a typo in the email address.